# Start docker containers on linux system startup from user directory

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I've downloaded two docker containers and already configure them.

So, now all I want is to start them on system startup.

They are in a path like

`/home/user/docker-mailserver`

`/home/user/docker-webserver`

Hosted on a Ubuntu 18.04.01 (x64)

On boot those docker containers are not running.

On login, those docker containers are starting.

I already tried to do something like

`docker run -it --restart unless-stopped fancydockercontainer:latest`

`docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped fancydockercontainer:latest`

But then when I do `docker ps` there where new containers added to the pool.

Is there a way to "re-route" the start process of those container to system start without completely delete / remove them?

Addition:
I started them like `docker-compose up -d mailserver`

Comment: So use docker-compose. And script it on startup with a systemd service file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @KamilCuk gave a hint to solve this with service, this was a possible solution.

Looks like this:

1. Create service file with command:
   `nano /etc/systemd/system/docker-mail.service`
2. Done stuff like that in the file

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Mailserver
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/docker-mailserver
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose up -d mail
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker-compose stop -d mail

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

3. Adding the new service to systemctl with `systemctl enable docker-mail.service`

After rebooting the server, this mailserver is available.

At this point, I was able to see the startup log with `journalctl -u docker-mail.service -b` (-b is just "boot")